# XML - Parsing selective nodes in R (xml2)

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have an XML input file. The file has data on some transactions. the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message xmlns:bs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02"
         xmlns="urn:bcsis" 
         xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
<bs:stmt>
  <bs:Bal>
    <bs:Tp>
      <bs:CdOrPrtry>
        <bs:Prtry>Outward</bs:Prtry>
      </bs:CdOrPrtry>
    </bs:Tp>
    <bs:Amt Ccy="USD">300.00</bs:Amt>
    <bs:CdtDbtInd>DBIT</bs:CdtDbtInd>
    <bs:Dt>
      <bs:Dt>2016-10-04</bs:Dt>
    </bs:Dt>
  </bs:Bal>
  <bs:Ntry>
    <bs:Amt Ccy="USD">300.00</bs:Amt>
  </bs:Ntry>
</bs:stmt>
<bs:stmt>
  <bs:Bal>
    <bs:Tp>
      <bs:CdOrPrtry>
        <bs:Prtry>Inward</bs:Prtry>
      </bs:CdOrPrtry>
    </bs:Tp>
    <bs:Amt Ccy="USD">250.00</bs:Amt>
    <bs:CdtDbtInd>DBIT</bs:CdtDbtInd>
    <bs:Dt>
      <bs:Dt>2016-10-04</bs:Dt>
    </bs:Dt>
  </bs:Bal>
  <bs:Ntry>
    <bs:Amt Ccy="USD">250.00</bs:Amt>
  </bs:Ntry>
</bs:stmt>
</Message>
```

I need to extract transaction amounts where the transaction type (bs:Prtry) is "Outward".

Here is what I have done so far:

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

d <- read_xml("~/CEED/sample1.dat") # read the file
in_out <- xml_find_all(d, ".//bs:stmt/bs:Bal/bs:Tp/bs:CdOrPrtry/bs:Prtry") # Transaction Type
out_txns <- in_out[which(in_out %>% xml_text() == "Outward")] # Select only Outward
```

This is what I need to do next:

- Navigate up to the bs:stmt tag within out_txns
- Find the  bs:Ntry, bs:Amt tags and extract the value

I have tried a few things (xml_find_parents) but not able to figure out right method of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was on the right track, but you were trying to do to much too soon.

The first step is to find all of the nodes and then save them as vector of nodes, the `in_out` variable.  Then parse and filter the "Outward" requested subset from the "in_out" vector of nodes to create `out_txns`.  From this reduced list of nodes, extracted the requested "amount" information.

```
library(xml2)
d<-read_xml("~/CEED/sample1.dat") # read the file

#find all of the stmt nodes
in_out <- xml_find_all(d, ".//bs:stmt") # Transaction Type

#filter the nodes and Select only Outward
out_txns <- in_out[xml_text(xml_find_first(in_out, ".//bs:Prtry")) == "Outward"] 
#Extract the amounts from the remianing nodes
amount<-xml_text(xml_find_first(out_txns, ".//bs:Amt"))
```